# onclick Function to close 'help window' not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've set up a div in a form which will display a help window and am wanting to set up an 'X' in the tope right hand corner with an onclick function to close the window. This div is located at the bottom of my HTML, right before the end body tag, is that the correct location?
Please note, I'm wanting to do this with the display:none tag, not show() or hide()
HTML

```
<div id="personalhelp"><p class="x"><a href="" onclick="close()">x</a></p>
<p class="help">Your personal information is needed to ensure we provide the most 
relevant information and options for you. We will never sell your personal
 information to third parties for any reason.</p>
<p class="help">Please fill in all required fields, 
these are identified with an asterisk (*)</p>
</div>
```

Function (Jquery)

```
function close() {
    var getid = $(this).parent.attr('id');
   console.log(getid);
   $(getid).css("display", "none");
}
```

CSS

```
#personalhelp {
    position: fixed;
    right: 10%;
    top: 10%;
    max-width: 60%;
    display: block;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    color: #000;
    margin: 5px auto;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    display: block;
}

.x {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1%;
    top:1%;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.help {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: As i mentioned in my answer below, change callback name from `close` to sth other, as there is browser native function `close`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `close()` method doesn't know what `this` is. jQuery has it's own `click()` function, you should use it and avoid `onclick="..."` in your HTML. Just do this:

```
$( ".x" ).click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Of course instead of `hide()` you could handle the "closing" in some other way. This is about the `click()` call.

Here is a running example:

```js
$(".x").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

```css
#personalhelp {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  max-width: 60%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  color: #000;
  margin: 5px auto;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: block;
}

.x {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1%;
  top: 1%;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.help {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="personalhelp">
  <p class="x"><a href="" onclick="close()">x</a></p>
  <p class="help">Your personal information is needed to ensure we provide the most relevant information and options for you. We will never sell your personal information to third parties for any reason.</p>
  <p class="help">Please fill in all required fields, these are identified with an asterisk (*)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: With both hide() and css("display", "none") it hides it for half a second then shows it again. What could be going wrong there?

Comment: Don't use both. `hide()` will set the css for you. That's what it does :) Just drop your `close()` method completely.

Comment: Oh no, I'm not using both. I tried both to see if there's a difference. I've copy and pasted what you've got but it doesn't remain hidden when the x is clicked on

Comment: i added a complete running example. Just see and try. I hope this helps!

Comment: Finally figured out what was causing the issue... I had another css for p#group which had display:block in there and for some reason it affected it and made it show up after the function ran. Your answer is the cleanest of all the responses. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The division tags always need to be located `<body>... </body>` section.

You just need to change your script code like this `document.getElementById(mydiv).style.display="none";`
or basically

```
$('#mydiv' ).hide();
```

This means in css display property set to none.
And maybe you try to write onclick event in script function...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your function `close`. There is other, browser native function with that name that is called instead. When changed to other name it works.
Also it should be `var getid = $(this).parent().attr('id');`.

```js
function closePersonalHelp() {
   var getid = $(this).parent().attr('id');
   console.log(getid);
   // line below is roughly equivalent to $(getid).hide();
   $(getid).css("display", "none");
}
```

```css
#personalhelp {
    position: fixed;
    right: 10%;
    top: 10%;
    max-width: 60%;
    display: block;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    color: #000;
    margin: 5px auto;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    display: block;
}

.x {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1%;
    top:1%;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.help {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="personalhelp"><p class="x"><a href="" onclick="closePersonalHelp()">x</a></p>
<p class="help">Your personal information is needed to ensure we provide the most 
relevant information and options for you. We will never sell your personal
 information to third parties for any reason.</p>
<p class="help">Please fill in all required fields, 
these are identified with an asterisk (*)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate you posted a running example. But i think if she uses jQuery, she should not be handling clicks via `onclick="..."`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#personalhelp").click(function(){
$(".help,div").css("display","none");
})
});
```

```css
#personalhelp {
    position: fixed;
    right: 10%;
    top: 10%;
    max-width: 60%;
    display: block;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    color: #000;
    margin: 5px auto;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    display: block;
}

.x {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1%;
    top:1%;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.help {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="personalhelp"><p class="x"><a href="">x</a></p>
<p class="help">Your personal information is needed to ensure we provide the most 
relevant information and options for you. We will never sell your personal
 information to third parties for any reason.</p>
<p class="help">Please fill in all required fields, 
these are identified with an asterisk (*)</p>
</div>
```